# function.php in wordpress. how do i insert html string in the head section?

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to target an html element (`<link>` & `<script>`) and wrap it with an html comment string (`<!-- -->`).

**from this:**

```
<link href="somecss" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="somejs" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

**to this**

```
<!-- <link href="somecss" rel="stylesheet" /> -->
<!-- <script src="somejs" type="text/javascript"></script> -->
```

I know this can be done in the frontend using some javascript/jquery, But I wanted to do it in the backend using the function.php of wordpress. Any ideas how?

Thanks!

Comment: This question is probably better suited to http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Do you want prevent loading wordpress script and styles or you just want add html comments?

Comment: I fear that the question can not be specifically answered with the information you have provided in your question. You need to specify which components cause the insertion of the tags you would like to comment-out.

Comment: I'm currently creating a child theme, It would be much easier for me if I block/remove the default css and script the main theme is loading.

Comment: I think I just want to add a comment on a specific line of element.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to prevent loading wordpress scripts you should use `wp_dequeue_script( $handle )` function. If can find description of $handle (default wordpress scripts) [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script#Default_scripts_included_with_WordPress).

If you want to prevent loading wordpress styles you should use `wp_dequeue_style( $handle )` function.

You should use this function after wordpress add default script and styles. You can use hook wp_enqueue_script with high priority param (so it runs last): `add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_enquue_scripts', 100);`

If your main theme have hardcoded scripts and styles in header.php - then you cannot prevent loading from functions.php

Comment: no, i think this is not what i am looking for. But thanks. I think its possible in php to find and replace. I just have now idea how.

Comment: do you think its possible to do a preg_replace()?

Comment: Yes, but i think it is bad solution.